# Extract Multiple Values from Dynamic Multi-line String

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, stream, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I'm working on a small Node.js app to parse a running log file in order to extract key values and generate custom alerts based on the results. However, I've now run into an issue for which I can't seem to find a solution.. If it's relevant at all, the specific log being parsed is a MS SourceSafe 2005 journal file.

For clarity, here are three examples of possible journal entries (some details changed for privacy reasons, structure kept intact):

```
$/path/to/a/project/folder
Version: 84
User: User1           Date: 14/01/27  Time: 12:15p
testBanner.rb added
Comment: Style and content changes based on corporate branding
Remove detector column on sc600 page
Styling tweaks and bug fixes

$/path/to/a/project/file.java
Version: 22
User: User2           Date: 14/01/29  Time: 12:34p
Checked in
Comment: Added fw updates to help fix (xxx) as seen in (yyy):
Changes include:
1) Peak tuning (minimum peak distance, and percentage crosstalk peak)
2) Dynamic pulses adjusted in run time by the sensor for low temperature climate
s
3) Startup noise automatic resets
4) More faults

$/path/to/a/project/folder
Version: 29
User: User3           Date: 14/01/30  Time: 11:54a
Labeled v2.036
Comment: Added many changes at this point, see aaVersion.java for a more comple
te listing.
```

So far, the following points are known:

- First entry line is **always** the relevant VSS database project or file path.
- Second entry line is **always** the relevant version of the above project or file.
- Third entry line **always** contains three values: `User:`, `Date:` and `Time:`.
- Fourth entry line is **always** the associated action, which can be any one of the following:

  - Checked in: {file}
  - {file} added
  - {folder} created
  - {file or folder} deleted
  - {file or folder} destroyed
  - Labeled: {label}
- Fifth entry line is an **optional** comment block, starting with `Comment:`. It may contain *any* type of string input, including new lines, file names, brackets, etc. Basically VSS does not restrict the comment contents at all.

I've found regex patterns to match everything *except* the "Comment:" section, not knowing how many new line characters may be included in the comment makes this really difficult for someone like me who doesn't speak regex very fluently at all..

So far, I've managed to get my app to watch the journal file for changes and catch only fresh data in a stream. My initial plan was to use `.split('\n\n')` on the stream output to catch each individual entry, but since comments may also contain any number of new lines at any position, this is not exactly a safe approach.

I found a module called [regex-stream](https://github.com/ornl-sava/regex-stream), which makes me think I don't need to collect the results in an array of strings before extracting details, but I don't really understand the given usage example. Alternatively, I have no problem with splitting and parsing individual strings, as long as I can find a reliable way to break the stream down into the individual entries.

In the end, I'm looking for an array of objects with the following entry structure for each update of the journal:

```
{
    path: "",
    version: "",
    user: "",
    date: "",
    time: "",
    action: "",
    comment: ""
}
```

Please note: If 100 files are checked in in one action, VSS will still log an entry for each file. In order to prevent notification spamming, I still need to perform additional validation and grouping *before* generating any notifications..

The current state of my app can be seen in [this Github repo](https://github.com/ZaLiTHkA/VSS-Notifier/blob/master/index.js). Could someone please help point me in the right direction here...?

Comment: There is no 100% fool-proof way to parse when the Comment section can contain anything. The next best choice would be to make some heuristics (e.g. when you find a path on its own in one line then it is the start of an entry, or you may even check the next line for version), and hoping that there is no crazy comment.

Comment: @nhahtdh, to be fair I do understand it's impossible to cater for every variation of the human factor.. From my research, I've got `/^\$\/.*$/g` to catch the first line of an entry (and similarly, `/^Comment:\s\/.*/g` for the start of the comment), but I'm very new to regex, so I need some help to figure out how to put it all together using a data stream as the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 100% fool-proof way to parse when the Comment section can contain anything. The next best choice would be to make some heuristics, and hoping that there is no crazy comment.

If we can assume that 2 new lines followed by a path signifies the start of an entry, then we can split on this regex (after you replace all variants of line separators to `\n`):

```
/\n\n(?=\$\/[^\n]*\n)/
```

The look-ahead `(?=pattern)` check that there is a path ahead `\$\/[^\n]*\n`, without consuming it.

To be extra sure, you can make it checks that the version line follows after the path:

```
/\n\n(?=\$\/[^\n]*\nVersion: \d+\n)/
```

Comment: Just did some reading up on regex groups and I can see what it's trying to do, but neither of these patterns match anything in my log... Trying with only `\$\/[^\n]*\n` does pick up the VSS path correctly, but as soon as I place it inside the look-ahead after `\n\n`, I get absolutely no matches (out of a theoretical 856 in my test file). Note: each case was tested in the format of `/pattern/`, both with and without the global switch. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA: It is not for matching. It is for `split` (which is currently `\n\n` in your code). You will do matching later when you loop through each of the entries.

Comment: Apologies, I may be using the wrong terminology here.. I was using that to try split the data stream. Logging the output it seems the `\r\n` new lines are not being replaced first though... Just updated my [Github repo](https://github.com/ZaLiTHkA/VSS-Notifier/blob/master/index.js), could you please have a look and see if I am putting things in the wrong place?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I just realised my error.. I was defining the regex patterns in variables and accidentally treating them as a string. After removing the wrapping quotes, new lines were replaced and sections were split as expected. :) Thanks so much for the help, I definitely know a lot more about regular expressions now.